# Como requisitar dados do dia no SQL com Unix Time Stamp (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, pdo, login

Ola estou com um com uma duvida aqui, estou criando um código para obter quantos usuários logaram no meu site hoje, porem eu salvo a ultima data que ele logou com Unix Time Stamp.

Eu só estou conseguindo obter o usuários que logaram nas ultimas 24 horas, porem, oque eu quero, é obter os usuário que logaram no dia.

Segue meu código:

```
$time_24h = time()-86400;

$users_today = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM {$table_prefix}_Users WHERE last_used > {$time_24h}")->rowCount();
```

Estou usando a conexão PDO.

quem puder me ajudar, ficaria muito grato, obrigado pela atenção :)

Comment: Depende da base de dados. Se puder postar qual é na pergunta, melhor, pois isto é algo para ser resolvido do lado do SQL e não do PHP. Trazer os dados para filtrar localmente gera tráfego e processamento desnecessário. A maior parte dos engines de DB permitem você fazer as conversões localmente, assim como obter o dia corrente de uma data para comparar com o de hoje

Comment: ola @Bacco, estou usando MySql.

Comment: Dei uma complementada com algumas considerações importantes. Qualquer dúvida avise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O ideal seria resolver na camada SQL, que depende do engine usado.

### Para MySQL

Basta fazer direto no select:

```
                       .--- converte de Unix para Timestamp, compativel com MySQL
                       |
SELECT ... WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used)) = CURRENT_DATE;
                  |                                |
                  '--- extrai a data, sem horas    '--- compara com data de hoje
```

### Resolvendo com PHP

Uma maneira de fazer com PHP é simplesmente determinar quando começa o dia em Unix Timestamp, e adicionar 86399 segundos, e localizar valores nesta faixa, ficando assim:

```
$hoje = time();                            // Pega o timestamp do servidor já em segundos
$iniciododia = ( $hoje % 86400 ) * 86400;  // "arredonda" para 0h00 do dia
$fimdodia = $iniciododia + 86399;           // e obtem o 23h59m59 do dia
```

Aplicando à sua *query*:

```
"SELECT * FROM {$table_prefix}_Users WHERE last_used BETWEEN $iniciododia AND $fimdodia"
                                                     |
           retorna dados entre 0h00m00 e 23h59m59 ---'
```

A solução dada serve para outros dias, trocando o `time()` pelo dia desejado, mas se quer somente os do dia atual, pode simplificar mais ainda:

```
$hoje = time();                            // Pega o timestamp do servidor já em segundos
$iniciododia = ( $hoje % 86400 ) * 86400;  // "arredonda" para 0h00 do dia
// ... desnecessário calcular o fim do dia para data atual ...
"SELECT * FROM {$table_prefix}_Users WHERE last_used >= $iniciododia"
```

### Se for só a contagem

Lembre-se que é desnecessário trazer todos os dados se quiser saber apenas a contagem. Da forma como está sua *query* original, você está trazendo todos os dados do DB para a data desejada desnecessáriamente. Considere fazer isto:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$table_prefix}_Users WHERE last_used >= $iniciododia"
```

aí basta pegar o único valor retornado em vez do `rowCount()`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode obter os usuarios logados no dia (no formato YYYY-mm-dd) usando a classe [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php) do php e a função [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) do MYSQL. Você poderia fazer assim:

```
//dataAtual  terá o formato YYYY-mm-dd, ou 0000-00-00, ano com quatro
//digitos, mes e dia com dois
$dataAtual = (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d');

//aqui você formata last_used no formato YYYY-mm-dd
$users_today = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM {$table_prefix}_Users WHERE
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used), '%Y-%m-%d') = {$dataAtual}")->rowCount();
```

A função [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-from_unixtime-function.php) converte do formato *Unix timestamp* para o formato `Datetime`, que por sua vez é formatado apenas para `Date`.

Comment: ola, eu estou usando o código que você esta sugerindo, porem o sql não esta achando nada, eu acho que o last_used, no código que você me mostrou, depois de uma pesquisada, teria que ser Y-m-d só que eu estou guardando as datas em Unix Time Stamp, se eu estiver errado, por favor me corriga. Obrigado por responder a minha pergunta :D

Comment: @Dante ola, realmente me confundi, achei que sua data estava no formato datetime. Já corrigi a resposta para se adaptar à sua situação. Basicamente converti de unix time stamp para datetime.

Comment: bom, tentei o novo código que você escreveu, mas não funcionou =/. A resposta do @Bacco era o que eu precisava, mas mesmo assim, obrigado pela ajuda